# write/save xml in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to create a stand alone pure flash application with external xml loading from the same dir. In that i want to update/overwirite my xml nodes and save it internally at run time (I dont want to go for fileReference class to save/overWrite my xml). when I load my apps next time it will react based on the updated xml.
I dont want go for AIR as it requires installation at end user side.
I cant use any server side script.

Is it possible in flash AS3.0?
Please suggest any possible solution.
Thanks..

Comment: Without using server-side help your only option is to use  the `FileReference` class.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible with [`FileReference.save()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29)
[here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/550/299) is an example saving `.txt` files

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reference. But fileRef.save() asks user to save the file. Its not happening internally in flash. :(

Comment: @shan s This is security issue, you cannot avoid it and save anything you want on user PC silently

Answer (score 0):

```
var file:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("test.txt");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeUTFBytes("text to save");
fileStream.close();
```

last time I tried this worked without any prompt as to where to save . . . if it helps anyone.
(above worked with mobile devices saving to SDcard) - you will need to allow (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.

Comment: This is AIR only (File, FileStream)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access files in Flash without AIR and FileReference, but you can save data in [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html). This is analogous to cookies in browser (but not tied to one). Data will be saved somewhere in "C:\Users\UserName\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\" directory (example for Win7) until user clears it or available disk size is exceeded.